# what is the difference

Tags: jsp, struts

hello what is the difference between
`<%+i%>` and `${i}`

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/howto-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<% %>` is a jsp scriptlet - you can write java code there
`<%= %>` is a jsp expression - you can put there java statements without a semicolon they will be printed on the page.
 
`${}` is an EL expression - you can use these instead of jsp expressions (actualy using EL is recommended) 
As a small example: `<%=request.getAttribute("query") %>` is the same like `${query}`